# Spring Data JPA - Many columns in where clause

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I need to determine if an entity has already been persisted. Unfortuantely, I do not have the id, but I can determine that the entity is already persisted if the value of six other fields of the entity match a persisted entity. I'm using Spring JPA repositories and know that I can do the following:

```
Test findByField1AndField2And...(String field1, String field2,...)
```

Is there a way to do something similar to:

```
 @Query("SELECT t "
           + "FROM Test t "
           + "WHERE "
           + "t.field1 = :testWithSomeFieldsPopulated.field1 and "
           + "t.field2 = :testWithSomeFieldsPopulated.field2 and ..." ) 
Test findByTest(@Param("testWithSomeFieldsPopulated") Test testWithSomeFieldsPopulated)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Spring Data JPA 1.7.0 or above, then you can accomplish this by [using SpEL in your `@Query` definition](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions).  So something like:

```
@Query("SELECT t "
           + "FROM Test t "
           + "WHERE "
           + "t.field1 = :#{#testWithSomeFieldsPopulated.field1} and "
           + "t.field2 = :#{#testWithSomeFieldsPopulated.field2} and ..." ) 
Test findByTest(@Param("testWithSomeFieldsPopulated") Test testWithSomeFieldsPopulated)
```

Comment: Thanks. I also need a row from Test to be returned if `t.fieldx is null and testWithSomeFieldsPopulated.fieldx is null`. Do you know if there is some way to set ansi nulls to off (SQL Server) in the `@Query` or some other way to accomplish this besides writing `(t.field1 = :#{#testWithSomeFieldsPopulated.field1} or (t.field is null and :#testWithSomeFieldsPopulated.field1 is null))` for each field? I know this is a follow up question. Your response above answers my original question and I plan to mark it as such.

Comment: I usually use [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) with a flag value for that sort of thing.